# Length of Returns (.search)

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

Is there a way to return the length of the results from the following line?

```
import wikipedia
query = input("What do you want to lookup? ")
wikipedia.search(query)
```

Thanks!

I know that .search will return the first ten results, and that you can specify more or less, but I'd like to be able to tell how many results there are.  I couldn't find this in this documentation, although I may not be looking in the right place.  Any help is appreciated! https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#api

Comment: ```len(wikipedia.search(query))``` should return the length of the function return

Comment: By default, wikipedia.search(query) passes in wikipedia.search(query, results=10, suggestion=False).  So len(wikipedia.search(query)) will never be greater than 10, even if there are more results possible.  Is there a way to figure out how many results are possible (say, if there are 50,000 results), and return than number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `wikipedia` package doesn't provide an API for the total number of hits. MediaWiki itself, however, does have such an option: [`srinfo=totalhits`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search).

Knowing this, getting the information from Wikipedia should be trivial (the documentation page linked above also has some code examples, Python included):

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', params = {
  'action': 'query',
  'format': 'json',
  'list': 'search',
  'srsearch': 'Foobar',
  'srinfo': 'totalhits'
}).json()

total_hits = response['query']['searchinfo']['totalhits']  # 131
```